# Script to append files with an extension to same basename files with different extensions

Tags: linux, bash, unix, append, sh

I'm trying to create a script to help with appending files of one extension to other files with the same basename of a different extension.

IE. Let's say I have a bunch of files under `/src` -- cat.html dog.html bird.html

and a bunch of files under `/scripts` -- cat.js dog.js bird.js
I want the script to go under /scripts dir and append the contents of cat.js to cat.html and repeat for every other file under /scripts

Comment: TBH looks like you want to also model dependency between files and use a build tool like `make`. What have you tried? What research did you do? Honestly, this looks like a trivial task..

Answer (score 1):

The simplest loop:

```
for script in ./scripts/*.js; do
     name="$(basename "$script" ".js")"
     cat "$script" >> "./src/$name.html"
done
```

should be enough.